# change event on multiselect does not trigger

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

Edit: Problem solved!

I have several multiselect fields in flask. When I change the selected items in one, I want to trigger a change in the other ones (right now, I am only trying to change one other field, because I don't know how to change several). However, this does not work at all. When I change the selected items, nothing changes, I don't even get an error message. Is a .change event not the right one to use with multiselect?
My multiselect field looks like this: [image] and I am using this multiselect: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-Checboxes-multiselect.html
I also have the following js in a separate script file:

```
$(function(){
    $param1_newlist = $('#param1');
    $param1_newlist.multiselect();
    });
```

My html imports are:

```html
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename="js/jquery.multiselect.js")}}"></script>
     <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/jquery.multiselect.css') }}">
```

and my multiselect form fields are all set up like the following:

```html
    <form action="/get_plot">
    <div style="float: left">
    <br><b>Param1</b><br>
    <select name="param1" multiple="multiple" id="param1" style="width:150px">
        {% for p in param_1_list %}
                {% if p in current_param_1 %}
                        <option selected value="{{ p }}">{{ p }}</option>
                {% else %}
                        <option value="{{ p }}">{{ p }}</option>
                {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
     </select>
     </div>
     </form>
```

My ajax request looks like this:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("#param1").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/selectform',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#param1').serialize(),
            success: function(selectOptions){
                $("#param2").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < selectOptions.length; i++){
                    $("#param2").append(
                        $("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", selectOptions[i][0])
                        .text(selectOptions[i][1])
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In flask, the code portion to handle the ajax request looks like this:

```py
    @app.route('/selectform', methods=['POST'])
    def updateselect():
         print(request.form)
         choices = ["test1", "test2"]
         response = make_response(json.dumps(choices))
         response.content_type = 'application/jsons'
         return response
```

Comment: Where is the script with relation to the form? Above or below it? Did you check in the console whether the `$.ajax` runs in the first place? Also, are these all your imports? Because jQuery plugins require jQuery.

Comment: @ChrisG There is the form, then another div, then the script (but the script is still inside the body). Unfortunately, I don't know too much about ajax,or frontend development for that matter, I just looked for error messages in the console and there weren't any, do I have to look somewhere else?

Comment: The click event handler is maybe not initialized. Try $(document).on('click', '#param1', function(){})

Comment: I tested this with the first multiselect plugin I found and it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L3uaoxk5/ Are you using this one (loudev)?

Comment: @Wimanicesir I am trying a change event, however, or is that the same type?

Comment: @ChrisG Strangely, that is not how my multiselect looks. I have checkboxes, maybe that is the reason? (see updated post)

Comment: @LizzAlice, Sorry misread, you can a .on('change'... as well though

Comment: Ok, can you link us to the one you're using?

Comment: @ChrisG I put the link in the post

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry, wrong link, updated

Comment: I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L3uaoxk5/ As you can see in the console, the change event works fine and triggers the POST request every time.

Comment: @ChrisG Then I really don't understand what I am doing wrong... I also added the ´´´$('#output').append("post triggered\n");``` to my code and nothing was printed... Could this be because I also have other js code in a separate file? See edited post

Comment: That output line only works if you also add the respective HTML line (`<pre id="output"></pre>`); anyway, order matters. Your `.multiselect()` call is wrapped in `$(function() {...});` which is a shortcut to ensure that the content is only called after the page has fully loaded. It is therefore also called after the change handler is assigned, breaking it in the process. Use a single script, put it at the end of body (but inside), and use the JS part from my fiddle as content.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you very much, that works!