# select.empty() removes other properties of select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a multiselect dropdown with checkboxes: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multi-Select-Checboxes-multiselect.html.
I am using flask and am in the process of implementing dynamic selects: when one is changed, it triggers a change event and the other is changed, too.
When filling the selects, it looks like this:

```
<form action="/get_plot">
<div style="float: left">
<br><b>Param1</b><br>
<select name="param1" multiple="multiple" id="param1" style="width:150px">
    {% for p in param1_list %}
            {% if p in current_param1 %}
                    <option selected value="{{ p }}">{{ p }}</option>
            {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ p }}">{{ p }}</option>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </div>
```

Everything works and looks like this: [image]

However, when I am triggering the on change event, I perform a $("#param2").empty(); and fill it again with

```
$("#param2").append(
$("<option></option>")
.attr("value", selectOptions[i][0])
.text(selectOptions[i][1])
              );
```

Then, the checkboxes are gone and the result looks like this:
[image]

Maybe important to know: I used

```
 selectOptions = JSON.parse(selectOptions)
```

Why is that and how can I fill the select without losing the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the `selectOptions` in a object like this:

{
'label 1' : 134,
'label 2' : 135,
'label 3' : 136,
}

Then you can iterate over `selectOptions` like this:

```
$el = $('#param2');
$el.empty();

$.each(selectOptions, function(key,value) {
  $el.append($("<option></option>")
     .attr("value", value).text(key));
});

$el.multiselect();  //change from html box to jquery
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that has the same consequence as mine.

Comment: Ok then we'll have to look at the content of selectOptions. Can you write it to the console (with console.log) and check if it conforms to the expected pattern?

Comment: Ok, so I deleted the JSON.parse because it changed the format of selectOptions. However now, although selectOptions looks like this: {"test2": 1, "test1": 1}, I get an error:Uncaught TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "{\"test2\": 1, \"te..."

Comment: That probably means that selectOptions is a string rather than an object. Can you set the object like this in order to test it: selectOptions = {"test2": 2, "test1" : 1};  ?

Comment: I did, now it looks like this again: Object { test2: 2, test1: 1 } and the problem is the same as in my post again.

Comment: Ok I see the problem. What's happening, is that in place of the fancy multiselect box you're getting the default html one. So you'd need to fix it after recreating it. I've updated the answer

Comment: If I do that, I get the following error: jQuery Plugin Error (Plugin: multiselect)
Can't convert element to checklist.
Expecting SELECT element with "multiple" attribute ; maybe this is, because I already used $el.multiselect(); above the $.each? However, if I remove the upper one, the intial dropdown isn't in the right format anymore.

Comment: Of course you should be able to use the plugin multiple times. I've created a small fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/epyzdvrL/ and there it works as expected. Please check if it helps you.

Comment: That's exactly how I used it... However, when I inserted $el.multiselect(); after defining $el (because I used it twice, too) the dropdown stays empty... Maybe that's an analogous problem? Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with js

Comment: That's really odd. I just updated the fiddle to https://jsfiddle.net/gLe21mxf/ in order to have two multiselect boxes and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Could it maybe behave differently, because it is inside an ajax request and in an on change event?

Comment: Also, if I put the $el = $('#param2'); $el.multiselect(); at the beginning of the fiddle (like in my script, where it is before the change event), the test1/test2 dropdown stays empty...

Comment: So I put the plugin function in event handlers - one timeout and one click event. And in both cases they work: https://jsfiddle.net/2onz8jbg/  So I'm guessing that is maybe not the problem. Maybe the variables to select the dropdown boxes have to be reassigned in the event handler because you are already using them outside (see javascript closure) and they refer to something else.

Comment: In the fiddle you posted just now, there is exactly the same problem that I have though O.o Could this be browser-specific?

Comment: Or rather, the format is wrong, before clicking the button.

Comment: Exactly, because clicking the button calls the function that updates the format.

Comment: So could the problem be that both the assignment of the options to my select and the update format-call are inside the click() event? My js looks roughly like this (had another problem yesterday), just that I use your each now instead of the for loop and added the multiselect call directly afterwards: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775101/change-event-on-multiselect-does-not-trigger

Comment: To me it looks like the change event on the original select-element won't work in combination with the plugin. Are you positive, that when selecting/unselecting elements in the style select box the change handler gets called?

Comment: Yes, the pictures I posted in this post show the select box before and after selecting boxes in the other select box and thus triggering the change event

Comment: Right, I forgot. It might be possible that is necessary to drop the object and recreate it completely instead of just emptying it. Some plugins don't work well being applied twice or more to the same element. Sometimes the plugin has a function to first remove its functionality.

Comment: Ok, I will try that! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me! :)